# Import html from another file as jsx in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to import a html code to a React component file from a separate file. In order to do that I tried to export it in separate file:

```
export const icon = () => {
  return (
    <svg width="62px" height="62px" viewBox="0 0 62 62">
      <path d="M7.75,33.5833333 L28.4166667,33.5833333 L28.4166667,7.75 L7.75,7.75 L7.75,33.5833333 Z M7.75,54.25 L28.4166667,54.25 L28.4166667,38.75 L7.75,38.75 L7.75,54.25 Z M33.5833333,54.25 L54.25,54.25 L54.25,28.4166667 L33.5833333,28.4166667 L33.5833333,54.25 Z M33.5833333,7.75 L33.5833333,23.25 L54.25,23.25 L54.25,7.75 L33.5833333,7.75 Z" id="path-1" fill="green" />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

Then inside my component file (class based component) I'm importing:

```
import { icon } from './../layouts/icons';
```

Then inside render method(inside return) I simply do:

```
{icon}
```

But this does not work. Any tips on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use SVGs like this in React often. You're basically there already. Capitalize 'icon' in your export and import, then just use it in the render method like any other component.

```
import { Icon } from '../../layouts/icons'

render() {
  return <Icon />
}
```

One gotcha to look out for is that when using SVGs as React components like this, you'll want to make sure that the attributes in your SVG file conform to JSX requirements (basically removing hyphens and camelcasing attribute names).

i.e., `strokeWidth` instead of `stroke-width`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's a SFC - stateless functional component. To make it work properly, either just call it:

```
{icon()}
```

or use as a JSX tag:

```
import { icon as Icon } from './../layouts/icons';

<Icon />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you export something as a function you should call it:

```
{icon()}
```

but you actually does not need to make an export for single entry. Thanks to webpack's loader system you can import whole file as a string:

```
import icon from '../icon.svg';

...
{icon}
```

You just need to configure [`svg-inli-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/svg-inline-loader/) 
for `*.svg` in webpack config like:

```
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
}
```

[UPD] [raw-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) is more straightforward way to achieve the same - it does not make any cleaning up and just returns file's content as a string